# Get upcoming Daylight Saving date

Tags: php, date, dst

How can I get the upcoming Daylight Saving date/time change via PHP for a specific timezone? I would like to output for example:

> Upcoming clock change for Berlin will be on 29.10.2017 at 3am.

Comment: I believe you'll need to download the IANA Time Zone Database: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: Hm, hope there is another way. I'm on shared host with this matter :)

Comment: Looks like the tz database is built into quite a few systems, per this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Use_in_software_systems . So you might be on a system that already has it downloaded.

Comment: It says it's built into PHP 5.1 and beyond.

Comment: Thanks, any pointers on how to use it? I'm stuck :)

Comment: This may be promising: http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php

Comment: Check the 2nd User Contributed Note on that page.

Comment: Thats great, just what i needed, thanks!

Comment: No sweat. Glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
$changes = $tz->getTransitions(strtotime("yesterday"), strtotime("+1 year"));
$n = count($changes);
$tnow = time();
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
    if($changes[$i]["ts"] > $tnow)
    {
        echo "Upcoming clock change for " . $tz->getName() . " will be on " . $changes[$i]["time"] . "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works good just the time/clock is a little off, it outputs 1:00 instead of 3:00 am.

Comment: I think it is in UTC. You may use ... will be on " . date("<format>", $changes[$i]["ts"]) . "\n";

Comment: p.s. After formatting the time i got 2:00 am instead of 3:00 so i've added 1 to changes index as i'm guessing it started with 0 hence one hour was off: date("H", $changes[$i + 1]["ts"])

Answer (score 0):

This feels kind of clunky, but it tests out OK.  The one-minute intervals are needed because DST changes are not limited to hourly boundaries.

```
<?php // demo/temp_g5wx.php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958720/php-get-upcoming-daylight-savings-date
 */
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// SET OUR TIME ZONE
$zone_obj = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

// USE ONE-MINUTE INTERVALS TO DETECT THE CHANGE
$minute = new DateInterval('PT1M');

// FOMATTING CHARACTER FOR DAYLIGHT SAVINGS TIME
$dst = 'I';

// GET A DATETIME OBJECT TO TEST
$time_obj = new DateTime('Today', $zone_obj);

$old_dst = $time_obj->format($dst);
$new_dst = $old_dst;

// ITREATE BY MINUTES
while ($old_dst == $new_dst)
{
    $time_obj->add($minute);
    $new_dst = $time_obj->format($dst);
}

// SHOW THE MOMENT OF CHANGE LIKE ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-11-05 01:00:00.000000"
var_dump($time_obj);
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I change to "Europe/Berlin" I get ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-10-29 02:01:00.000000"